# Custom itemize alignment

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize

I intend to combine the itemize environment with the minipage environment to prevent paragraphs from appearing on separate pages, but as a result the alignment of the bullet and the text changes from
[image: Desired result]
to
[image: Actual result]
To clarify, I'm looking for a way to combine minipage and itemize/enumerate like the code below to get the same spacing between the bullet and text as in the first example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    Lorem\\
    Ipsum
  \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
The option `[t]` for minipage has been suggested, and generally works, but is not fully compatible with other environments. When pairing it with the array environment as follows, the bullet resets to a centered position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    $\begin{array}{rcl}
    x &=& y\\
    y &=& x\\
    2x &\neq& 5y
    \end{array}$
  \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Array doesn't respect option t]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using option `[t]` for `minipage` does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % Thanks to Bernard
    \lipsum[1]

    \lipsum[2]
  \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** The `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` is only for showing margin, you can delete it in actual document.

#### Edit:

As for the conflict:

The reason for the conflicts is that the whole `array` environment is considered to be an element, like a letter in the line, which means the `array` environment will be "centerized" with the first line.

A quick and tricky way to solve this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{$\begin{array}{rcl}
    x &=& y\\
    y &=& x\\
    2x &\neq& 5y
    \end{array}$}
  \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A standard solution for the `array`: We use `[t]` once again (thanks to koleygr):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    $\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
    x &=& y\\
    y &=& x\\
    2x &\neq& 5y
    \end{array}$
  \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even with the simpler `\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}`, it works.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but for the OP's example only. If he/she has a paragraph in the item, we have to do some calculations so that it doesn't get "Overfull hbox...". Warnings are not fatal, but they annoy me ;-) and the output is bad then.

Comment: That's right, but check what happens replacing `\textwidth` with `\linewidth`. No `\dimexpr` necessary.

Comment: @Bernard Oh it is so simple! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I have yet one conflict left, and it's with the `lstlisting` environment from the `listings` package. Using the same logic with which you solved the array exception, I get a ton of errors I'm not expecting.

Comment: @Iterniam `lstlisting`, and `minted` or `verbatim` are very special environments. However, do you really want to have a `lstlisting` in an `\item`? It is very rare!

Comment: @JouleV It's for code fragments in homework, for which I use a combination of `\section` and `itemize`. I found that for `lstlisting` the command `\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}` before starting the environment works well.

Comment: @Iterniam I'm very glad to hear that you find a solution yourself! Congratulations.

Comment: For the array a `\begin{array}[t]` should work too

Comment: @koleygr Thank you very much! It is very useful. I don't know about this before :)

Comment: welcome... We all learn every day... (You already have my +1)

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox{\mybottombox} % Box to save the text of the command 
\newlength{\mybottomlength} % The length of our text inside the command
\newlength{\availafter} % The available length left on the page after placing our text


% Optional argument is the minimum length after the nobottom text for not pagebreak. Change it to your needs
\newcommand{\mnobreak}[2][0pt]{\savebox{\mybottombox}{\vbox{#2}}\setlength{\mybottomlength}{\ht\mybottombox}%
\setlength{\availafter}{\dimexpr\textheight-\mybottomlength-\pagetotal\relax}\ifdim\availafter<#1%
\pagebreak\noindent\usebox{\mybottombox}%
\else%
\noindent\usebox{\mybottombox}%
\fi%
}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

To clarify, I'm looking for a way to combine minipage and itemize/enumerate like the code below to get the same spacing between the bullet and text as in the first example. To clarify, I'm looking for a way to combine minipage and itemize/enumerate like the code below to get the same spacing between the bullet and text as in the first example.

\begin{itemize}
 \item \mnobreak{Lorem\\Lipsum\\Lorem\\Lipsum\\Lorem}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Remove the last Lorem to see that the item would break with it.

Source: my old answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396216/120578)

Output:

[image]