# Prevent tcolorbox from being at the bottom of a page

Tags: tcolorbox

Is there any way to prevent a tcolorbox from being at the bottom of a page, and instead push it to the next page automatically?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{outcome}{before skip=2em, after skip=1em}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample}

\begin{outcome}
    This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
\end{outcome}

\lipsum[1-6]

This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 

\begin{outcome}
    Sample text.
\end{outcome}

This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far?

Comment: You might be interested in the `float` and the `floatplacement` options of `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @leandriis I've added the code I've used to get the box? Thank you! The ```float``` option only seems to allow me to force it to the top or the bottom though, I just want to avoid placing the grey box at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to a full MWE. That is a small compilable document, that includes the documentclass you use, the *relevant*  packages as well as some example text and a box that is currently placed at the bottom of a page.

Comment: @leandriis Hi sorry, I've edited my post. Thank you!

Comment: Something went wrong with your edit: There is still no `\documentclass` line.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Whoops, edited again. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{outcome}{before skip=2em, after={%
    \tcb@parfillskip@check\par\ifvmode\nointerlineskip
    \nobreak
    \addvspace{\glueexpr 1em-\parskip}\fi
    }}
\makeatother
```

The code is copied verbatim from the definition of `after skip/.style` in `tcolorbox.sty`, with `#1` replaced by your hard coded value `1em` and a `\nobreak` added in order to keep the box together with the following paragraph.

Comment: This works, but seems to change the spacing after the box (https://imgur.com/a/M6RdFWR). I've tried it in my document as well, and it seems to cause different boxes to have different spacing.

Comment: Does it work better now? It seems so, to me.

Comment: Honestly though, I can't understand the reason for wrapping code in `\ifvmode…\fi`, given the `\par` immediately preceding. That should *guarantee* that we're in vertical mode, unless someone has redefined `\par` to do something unexpected of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way from the old answer of mine [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396216/120578):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\mybottombox} % Box to save the text of the command 
\newlength{\mybottomlength} % The length of our text inside the command
\newlength{\availafter} % The available length left on the page after placing our text


% Optional argument is the minimum length after the nobottom text for not pagebreak. Change it to your needs
\newcommand{\nobottom}[2][60pt]{\savebox{\mybottombox}{\vbox{#2}}\setlength{\mybottomlength}{\ht\mybottombox}%
\setlength{\availafter}{\dimexpr\textheight-\mybottomlength-\pagetotal\relax}\ifdim\availafter<#1%
\pagebreak\noindent\usebox{\mybottombox}%
\else%
\noindent\usebox{\mybottombox}%
\fi%
}%

\newtcolorbox{outcome}{before skip=2em, after skip=1em}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample}

\begin{outcome}
    This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
\end{outcome}

\lipsum[1-6]

This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 

\nobottom{%
\begin{outcome}
    Sample text.
\end{outcome}}

This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 

\end{document}
```

[image]